# Occasional "Input string was not in a correct format" error

Tags: c#

This is the code in my project, I ran it once and it worked but the next time an trying it, it doesn't with the error "Input string was not in a correct format". Need your urgent assistance.

```
con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConClass.conString();
string newstud = "SELECT MAX(StudentRegNo) FROM NewStudent";
if (search(newstud) != "")
  RegNo = (int.Parse(search(newstud)) + 1);
else
  RegNo = 1;
lblStuReg.Text = "AP/HQ/" + RegNo.ToString();
```

Comment: what does the search() method do?

Comment: What is the `search` method? Why don't you instantiate `SqlConnection` within the search method. You also call search twice. Just could just `RegNo = GetNextStudentRegNo();` and that method would do sql query `SELECT MAX(StudentRegNo)+1 FROM NewStudent`

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong way to create a new id number. You're setting up a race condition if two people add students at about the same time.

Comment: the lblStuReg display the current available Student Registration Number, so the search() method searches for the current max number already allocated so that the next number can be allocated

Answer (score 3):

This particular message is coming from the `int.Parse` call because the result of `search(newStudQuery)` is not returning a number value.  To protect against this either catch the exception or use `TryParse` instead

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryResult)) {
  if (int.TryParse(search(newStudQuery), out RegNo) {
    RegNo += 1; }
  } else { 
    // Handle the case where the result is not a number
  }
} else {
  RegNo = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error very likely means that `search(newstud)` did return a string which was not empty but which also could not be parsed as integer.

I assume `search` is performing a SQL query. You should store the result in a variable otherwise it is calling it twice and use `int.TryParse` to parse the result (it also makes the code a bit shorter):

```
string newStudQuery = "SELECT MAX(StudentRegNo) FROM NewStudent";
string queryResult = search(newStudQuery);
if (!int.TryParse(queryResult, out RegNo))
{
    RegNo = 0;
}
RegNo++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could simply query for

```
string newstud = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(StudentRegNo) + 1, 1) FROM NewStudent";
```

... the questions sounds like your creating a id sequence in your application - this should rather be handled by a auto-incrementing your StudentRegNo inside your database.

---

Just for the sake of excercise - you could shorten things down to

```
int RegNo; // assuming you also just declared it somewhere above
int.TryParse(search(newStudQuery), out RegNo);
RegNo++;
```

But as Luke pointed out, `search()` should also be refactored to return something more usefull instead of a string that could be empty or even a null reference.

Comment: I think you mean `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(StudentRegNo) + 1, 1) FROM NewStudent`

Comment: If it's SQL Server we're dealing with ... I'll update but the whole thing looks like "don't do this" anyway.

Comment: I think you mean *It is SQL Server we're dealing with...* `con = new SqlConnection();` gives it away.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
RegNo = (int.Parse(search(newstud)) + 1);
```

`search(newstud)` isn't returning a number.

edit: Use:

```
con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConClass.conString();
string newstud = "SELECT MAX(StudentRegNo) FROM NewStudent";
try{
  RegNo = (int.Parse(search(newstud)) + 1);
}
catch{
  RegNo = 1;
}
lblStuReg.Text = "AP/HQ/" + RegNo.ToString();
```

edit: Actually, you should probably go with Jared's answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better using TryParse(int) - I would expect it carries the same overhead as the Try{..} Catch{..} - and it's a whole lot cleaner!